# How do you say this phrase in latin? Venisti, vedisti, you destroyed?

Tags: vocabulary

Can someone help me with this expression?
I want it to say "You came, you saw, you destroyed".
I know the first two parts... but I can't seem to find how to say the last one. 
I would appreciate the help. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's worth pointing out, you translate *meaning*, not words. You have to decide what exactly you mean by "destroy", since (for example) Godzilla destroying Tokyo means something very different from a sports team destroying its opponent.

Answer (score 18):

Well, to get the simple problem out of the way, it should be *vidisti*, not *vedisti*, but I assume that was just a mistyped letter.

On to the main problem: You say you cannot find a word for destroy. The best path to finding a word is to consult a dictionary. An excellent English-Latin dictionary which is available online in several places is the one by William Smith and Theophilus D Hall. You can find it [here](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries), for example (you may want to uncheck the other dictionaries, although they usually do no harm).

When we look up “destroy”, we find that the Romans apparently had a thing for destruction, because they sure had [a lot of words](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=sh6851) for it:

- perdo
- everto
- destruo
- perimo
- interimo
- deleo
- exstinguo
- corrumpo
- tollo
- exscindo
- disturbo
- pessumdo

An embarrassment of riches! Which one should you choose? A few of these might ring a bell; for example:

- *destruo* is, of course, the ancestor of English's very own “destroy”
- *exstinguo* likewise for “extinguish”
- *deleo* is known from one of the most famous Latin quotations: *Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam* (“Apart from that I think Carthage must be destroyed”), presumably frequently uttered on various occasions pointedly unrelated to the conflict between Carthage and Rome by the affable Roman senator and all-around good guy, Cato the Elder

The dictionary (and this is why it is a good one) even gives you helpful hints pertaining to subtle differences in meaning. For example, it says *destruere* is used when speaking of structures (that are being destroyed), whereas *interimere* is used when speaking of lives (being taken). You have to decide which is most appropriate for your use.

But let us say you go with *perimere*, which looks pretty generic. All that is left to do is put it in the second-person singular active indicative perfect form, like *venisti* and so on. And so we end up with:

> Venisti, vidisti, peremisti.

Comment: +1 for the rhyme and for pointing out the typo I had reiterated too! I couldn't help but go with Cato, though. :)

Comment: This had so much on-point information. Learned a lot. Thanks. I appreciate your time and effort lot.

Comment: “The best path to finding a word is to consult a dictionary” - This should be the motto of this and many more websites and forums about languages.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva You can never go wrong with Marcus Porcius :)

Answer (score 15):

The verb you're looking for is *delere*, whose second-person singular perfect active indicative is *delevisti*. Here, though, its syncopated form is clearly better:

***Venisti, vidisti, delesti.***

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I wanted.